# R - "ksvm object contains no probability model" error for one class svm?

Tags: r, svm, kernlab

I am trying to detect outliers and output as probabilities using one class svm in R kernlab package. The import data and model building process all seems fine, but when I tried to predict the model by specifying type="probabilities" it gives me the "ksvm object contains no probability model" error. I am using version 3.1.0 and here is my code.

```
mydata <- read.table("C:/Temp/MyTrainData.csv", header = TRUE, sep=",", dec=".")
mydata1 <- as.matrix(mydata)
model <- ksvm(mydata1,type="one-svc",kernel="rbfdot",kpar="automatic",prob.model = TRUE)
mytest <- read.table("C:/Temp/MyTestData.csv", header = TRUE, sep=",", dec=".")
mytest1 <- as.matrix(mytest)
pred <- predict(model,mytest1,type="probabilities")
```

It gives the following:

```
Error in .local(object, ...) : 
  ksvm object contains no probability model. Make sure you set the paramater prob.model in ksvm during training.
```

As shown above, I have already set prob.model = TRUE for ksvm function and didn't receive any error at that stage until I tried to predict the new data. I have also tried e1071 package but get the similar error. Just wonder if the probability option is allowed for one class svm? If not, is there any workaround on this or is it supported by other popular software (eg, RapidMiner)?